# PayPal IPN Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal-ipn

When I ran the following code through the IPN simulator the simulator said it worked however my page received a INVALID response.

I did some reading and paypal said it uses charset UTF-8 but when I changed to that the simulator failed and I received no response.

The code runs on pageload

```
string postUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PayPalSubmitUrlSandBox"];
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postUrl);

    //Set values for the request back
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
    string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
    string ipnPost = strRequest;
    strRequest = "cmd=_notify-validate&" + strRequest;
    req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

    //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
    StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(),
                             System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
    streamOut.Write(strRequest);
    streamOut.Close();

    StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
    string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
    streamIn.Close();


    if (strResponse == "VERIFIED")
    {
       //removed this because I don't think it is what is causing the trouble }


        }
        else if (strResponse == "INVALID")
        {
       //removed this because I don't think it is what is causing the trouble


        }
        else
        {
       //removed this because I don't think it is what is causing the trouble
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out... not really sure what changed from the previous code. I just found code on a tutorial and did some minor modifications.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing;


public partial class paypal_IPNHandler : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string payerEmail;
    string paymentStatus;
    string receiverEmail;
    string amount;
    /// <summary>
    /// Process an incoming Instant Payment Notification (IPN)
    /// from PayPal, at conclusion of a received payment from a
    /// customer
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // receive PayPal ipn data

  // extract ipn data into a string
  byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(Request.ContentLength);
  string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);

  // append PayPal verification code to end of string
  strRequest = "cmd=_notify-validate&" + strRequest;

  // create an HttpRequest channel to perform handshake with PayPal
  HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");
  req.Method = "POST";
  req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

  // send data back to PayPal to request verification
  StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
  streamOut.Write(strRequest);
  streamOut.Close();

  // receive response from PayPal
  StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
  string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
  streamIn.Close();

  // if PayPal response is successful / verified
  if (strResponse.Equals("VERIFIED"))
  {
    // paypal has verified the data, it is safe for us to perform processing now

    // extract the form fields expected: buyer and seller email, payment status, amount
    payerEmail = Request.Form["payer_email"];
    paymentStatus = Request.Form["payment_status"];
    receiverEmail = Request.Form["receiver_email"];
    amount = Request.Form["mc_gross"];


  }
    // else
    else
    {
      // payment not complete yet, may be undergoing additional verification or processing

      // do nothing - wait for paypal to send another IPN when payment is complete
    }
  String insertConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BeachConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
  using (SqlConnection insertcon = new SqlConnection(insertConnString))
  using (SqlCommand cmdinsert = insertcon.CreateCommand())
  {
      string insertprofile = "INSERT INTO Test (Status, Text) VALUES (@Status, @Text)";
      cmdinsert.CommandText = insertprofile;
      cmdinsert.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strResponse.ToString();
      cmdinsert.Parameters.Add("@Text", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = strRequest.ToString();
      cmdinsert.Connection.Open();
      cmdinsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to the following:

```
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
strRequest = "cmd=_notify-validate&";
req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;
```

Also, make sure you're logged into the sandbox BEFORE you do the test...

Comment: No luck. It is hard to troubleshoot without error messages but since paypal is posting to my page I can't receive them.

Comment: You've entered the return URL in paypal admin and made sure not to use PDT as well as IPN?

Comment: figured it out used some code from another tutorial...however it looks pretty much the same